# Displaying TableView and CustomCell troubles on iPhone4s

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6gm

I have some trouble with the appearance of my tableviews and cells on the iphone4s. Within the simulator and on new devices everything is fine.

1. UITableViewController
   The custom table cell (picture 1) isn't presented correctly. All the labels etc. lie on top of each other. They should be shown one below the other like they do on the simulator.
2. ViewController with TableView
   The other custom cells even don't show on the iPhone4s only a gray square appears.

I'm using Auto Layout. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Here's the code:
1st picture:

```
import UIKit

class FeedController: TableViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // adjusting text size without quitting app
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "onContentSizeChange:",
        name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)

    // set table row height
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    // removes the back button after clicked on send button to write a post
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    // refresh control
    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.refreshControl!.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
}

func reloadFeed(note: NSNotification){
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject){
    self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
}

// called when the text size was changed by the user 
func onContentSizeChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PDeliversStatusAlerts {
let notifCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

override init() {
    super.init()
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "displayConnectionLostAlert", name: kConnectionLostNotification, object: self)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "displayConnectionLostAlert", name: kConnectionLostNotification, object: self)
}


func displaySimpleAlert(#title:String, message:String){
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func displayModalDialog(#title: String, message: String, yesHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)?, noHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)?) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: noHandler))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func push(sender: AnyObject) {
}

//Tableview
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

2nd picture:

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: ViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var followedFeed    : FollowedHashtagFeed?
var hottestFeed     : HottestHashtagFeed?
var nearbyFeed      : NearbyHashtagFeed?

var hashtagFeed     : HashtagFeed?

@IBAction func hottestButtonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    hashtagFeed = FeedFactory.instance().hottestHashtagFeed()
    notifCenter.removeObserver(self)
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "reloadFeed", name: hashtagFeed?.notificationName, object: nil)
    hashtagFeed!.subscribe()
    reloadFeed()
}

@IBAction func nearbyButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    hashtagFeed = FeedFactory.instance().nearbyHashtagFeed()
    notifCenter.removeObserver(self)
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "reloadFeed", name: hashtagFeed?.notificationName, object: nil)
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveLocationPermissionNeededNotification:", name: "location_permission_needed", object: nil)
    hashtagFeed!.subscribe()
    reloadFeed()
}

@IBAction func followedButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    hashtagFeed = FeedFactory.instance().followedHashtagFeed()
    notifCenter.removeObserver(self)
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "reloadFeed", name: hashtagFeed?.notificationName, object: nil)
    hashtagFeed!.subscribe()
    reloadFeed()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //set table row height
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    //load feed cell
    var nipName=UINib(nibName: "NextTableCell", bundle:nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "nextCell")

    followedButtonTapped(followedButton)


    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    println("Frame Height:")
    println(tableView.frame.height)
    println(tableView.bounds.height)
    println("Frame Width:")
    println(self.tableView.frame.width)
    println(self.tableView.bounds.width)

    /*
    hashtagFeed = FeedFactory.instance().followedHashtagFeed()

    //subscribe to feed changes
    notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "reloadFeed", name: hashtagFeed?.notificationName, object: nil)
    hashtagFeed!.subscribe()*/
}

func didReceiveLocationPermissionNeededNotification(note: NSNotification){
    displayModalDialog(
        title:      "Location Permission Needed",
        message:    "In order to use this functionality the app needs your permission to use location data - do you want to give this permission now?",
        yesHandler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) in LocationHelper.instance().askForPermission()
        },
        noHandler: nil
    )
}



//Tableview

func reloadFeed(){
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return hashtagFeed!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("nextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as NextTableCell
    let hashtag = hashtagFeed!.toArray()[indexPath.row]
    cell.loadItem(hashtag)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I edited my question, do you need sth. else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue can present itself when the constraints set up for the cell's subviews do not enforce a specific height for the cell.

For example, if you have a cell that contains a single subview, and the subview has top/bottom/left/right constraints to its superview (nearest neighbor, i.e. the cell's contentView) of 10px, but the subview itself does not have a height constraint, the cell will not be laid out properly.

This can look like all cells on top of one another, or all cells presented with the default 44px height.

To fix the issue (if we're working with the example view hierarchy of a cell with a single subview), define a height constraint for the subview. You might also need to set the height constraint's priority to something less than 1000.

Not sure if this will fix your specific issue, but it's fixed similar issues for me, so presenting it here as an option.

For what it's worth, I'm fairly certain that your issue is constraints-related, which means the code above wont really help answer the question.

Comment: I think it's constraint-related too. But the weird thing is that it works absolutely fine for the iphone5 or newer devices. The cells and the table views are shown correctly. Only on the iphone4s the cells aren't presented as I want them.. Even on the simulator (iphone4s) the cells are shown correctly..